# X hangs after hibernating Fedora 18

Tags: fedora, xorg, hibernate

Yesterday I was using my FC18, of which I haven't updated significant packages for long time, maybe just a few desktop apps some weeks ago. On shutdown I chose to hibernate it, as I usually do and as I have been doing for months almost daily.

Today I turned it on just to have X hanging after boot. I tried hard reboot, passing the `noresume` option to grub so that it didn't use the booting data on swap, summoning a login screen and then shutting down by command-line, etc...
Nothing changes. Everything loads, even wpa-supplicant, gdm..., at least according to the messages displayed on boot, and then I still end up stuck on a default wallpaper with my working mouse pointer.

On the second time I tried rebooting a graphical message, with a sad-faced computer, appeared saying "It seems an error occurred, contact administrator."
If I try to start X again on another login screen via `startx` it still hangs.

I have made no recent changes to X or system's configuration, nor any important update. The only thing I did differently from usual was hibernating while having some more videos running: a video file played on VLC and some Firefox tabs with flash videos, which, however, were not playing all together at the same time. I usually hibernate after having closed a few apps, that's it.

Do you have any idea on what's going on? what should I check to fix the problem?